# Pattern matching Inequality

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to extract arguments from instances of Inequality. Following doesn't work, any idea why and how to fix it?

```
Inequality[1, Less, x, Less, 2] /. Inequality[a_, _, c_, _, e_] -> {a, c, e}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Inequality[1,Less,x,Less,2] /. HoldPattern[Inequality[a_,_,b_,_,c_]] -> {a, b, c}


Out: {1, x, 2}
```

Comment: I wondered why `HoldPattern` is required, and `Trace` reveals why: `Inequality[a_,_,b_,_,c_]` becomes `Inequality[a_, _, c_] && Inequality[c_, _, e_]`. So, it no longer matches what you expect.

Comment: @rcollyer Yep, a pattern is evaluated. Try this example **MatchQ[a/b, _/_] // Trace**

Comment: That would drive me nuts for hours trying to get that pattern to work.

Comment: @Yaroslav - Thanks for asking this! And +1 for the answer. @rcollyer - it HAS driven me nuts for hours. :P

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can do this:

Inequality[1, Less, x, Less, 2] /. 
 Literal @ Inequality[ a_ , _ , c_ , _ , e_ ] -> {a, c, e}

ADL

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use standard access to subexpression?

expr = Inequality[1, Less, x, Less, 2];
{a,c,e} = {expr[[1]], expr[[3]], expr[[5]]};

Comment: Because I need to replace all inequalities with equalities in something like this -- http://pastebin.com/wN2ENmL6